# how to display one location from an array of location based on sensor number

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have an array of latitudes and longitudes like this

I can display all these locations on google map but how to display one location based on sensor number.

```
var locations = [
      ['Sensor 1', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
      ['Sensor 2', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
      ['Sensor 3', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
      ['Sensor 4', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
      ['Sensor 5', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your code, so it's hard to know.

Here is a working solution, by calling initialize when clicking on html elements

This resets the map with a new marker.

- Defined initialize() with parameter "select"
- Beneath the map variable (but inside initialize) made a marker, which picks the data using the previously defined "select" parameter.
- Used html element to call initialize with parameter value.

Normal Google map otherwise.

It really helps if we can see your code, in future.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #map-canvas {
        width: 500px;
        height: 400px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script>

    var locations = [
      ['Sensor 1', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
      ['Sensor 2', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
      ['Sensor 3', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
      ['Sensor 4', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
      ['Sensor 5', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
    ];

    function initialize(select) {
      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.890542, 151.274856);
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 9,
        center: myLatlng
      }
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[select][1], locations[select][2]),
        map: map
      });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p onclick="initialize(0)">Sensor 1</p>
    <p onclick="initialize(1)">Sensor 2</p>
    <p onclick="initialize(2)">Sensor 3</p>
    <p onclick="initialize(3)">Sensor 4</p>
    <p onclick="initialize(4)">Sensor 5</p>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```